# $var->toJson Does not show the complete message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to show to the customer all the items duplicated while using a CSV files importer in Laravel.

This is my line of code:

```
$importador->articulos_no_encontrados = $articulos_no_encontrados->toJson();
```

And the view shows the duplicities in an array, but the message end in [...] meaning that indeed there are more items to show but the customer cannot see them:

[image: Error in Json format]

Can you help me to find a solution to show the full message with all the items instead of the [...]? Currently I'm using dd() everytime that happens but the customer should be able to see it too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a 'problem' from your frontend, and not from laravel per se... check you blade files, or whatever you're using for displaying that info

Answer (score 0):

Output of text fields are limited to 50 characters by default. Set the limit property to a higher value, see more info on https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#text

You might want to use this field component https://github.com/ziming/json-field-for-backpack to make the output more readable for your users